# Colocar N valores em ordem

Tags: python-3.x

Preciso fazer um programa que leia `n` números (quantidade indeterminada) e depois coloque eles em ordem. A condição de parada é o número 0.

Pensei em jogar esse valores para uma lista e depois ordená-los.
Fiz um laço while, porém, obviamente ele só vai guardar o último valor.

Comment: Coloque a sua tentativa na pergunta para que consiga de facto perceber onde errou e ter uma ajuda mais direcionada.

Comment: Tente colocar o código do que tentou fazer.

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde, tudo bem?
Cara, depende do jeito que você está fazendo as coisas, estou sem o python neste computador, mas acredito que este código fará o que está pensando, espero que retorne se deu, ou não, certo. Ficarei aguardando.

```
    lis_ord = []

    while True:

    num = int(input("Por favor, adicione um número a lista [insira 0 para sair]: "))

    if num > 0 or num < 0:
        lis_ord.append(num)
        lis_ord.sort
        print("O número foi adicionado com sucesso, sua lista é:")
        print(lis.ord)

    elif num == 0:
        print("Obrigado por usar o programa. Encerrando.")
        break

    else:
        print("Comando inválido. Use apenas números.")
```

O code block acima deverá funcionar da seguinte maneira:

Cria uma lista e a vincula a variavel lis_ord;
Enquanto verdadeiro, pede que o usuário forneça um input, armazenado na variavel num, depois ele organiza a lista do menor ao maior, printa que o numero foi adicionado, e exibe a lista em seu estado atual;
Se o input for maior ou menor que zero, ele coloca em apenso a lista lis_ord;
Se o input for zero, ele encerra o programa;
Se o input for uma STRING, ou um FLOAT, por exemplo, printa comando inválido, e retorna ao input do usuário;

Talvez tenha algo errado, pois não tive como testar, mas, qualquer coisa, retorne com uma resposta e eu tentarei ajudar novamente.
Colocar seu código também seria de grande ajuda, para entender onde o erro está ocorrendo.
Espero ter ajudado, abraços.

Comment: Deu certo! Muito obrigado, cara. Boas festas pra ti.